# QThread - No such slot

Tags: c++, qt

Defined `ComSendCallToScreenThread` inherited from `QThread`:

```
class ComSendCallToScreenThread : public QThread 
{
    private slots:
        void readAnswer();
        void pauseSendingRequests();
};

void ComSendCallToScreenThread::run()
{
    connect(m_senderCom, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(readAnswer()));
    connect(m_senderCom, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(pauseSendingRequests()));
}
```

At running error reported:

```
Object::connect: No such slot QThread::readAnswer() in ComSendCallToScreenThread.cpp:47
Object::connect: No such slot QThread::pauseSendingRequests() in ComSendCallToScreenThread.cpp:48
```

What caused the connect failure ?

Comment: I noticed you subclassed QThread, so i have to ask if you've read [this](http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/20691)? It states `a QThread should only manage a thread, not process data.`.

Comment: @thuga Mind to provide any suggestions ? Really appreciate that.

Comment: Well like it shows in the examples of the link i provided, the correct way to create a thread is to subclass `QObject`. Then you move that object to a thread that you created with `new QThread`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Put a `Q_OBJECT` right after class definition:

```
class ComSendCallToScreenThread : public QThread 
{
   Q_OBJECT
```

Qt4 [documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/signalsandslots.html):

> All classes that contain signals or slots must mention **Q_OBJECT** at the
>   top of their declaration. They must also derive (directly or
>   indirectly) from QObject.

Comment: And don't forget to call `qmake` after adding `Q_OBJECT` macro.